# Android: Select certain theme for certain view

Tags: android, android-view, android-theme, numberpicker

My goal is to use `Theme.Light` in `NumberPicker` while using a different theme in my application. I generate the `NumberPicker` at runtime. How do I achieve this? Any suggestions and links are appreciated!

Comment: 'How do I do this?' - Have you tried anything so far? If so, what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried skimming through all methods for the NumberPicker and Googling around, but I am unsure what to search or look for as I have never done anything like this.  All I can find is how to set the Theme for an entire Activity, not a single component.  Any links or help searching is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Styles and themes are read from attributes (android:textColor, etc.).

If you are inflating a layout in your view, then you can customize your layout.

If you want to change the style of all NumberPickers, then you just have to customize the style in XML:

Example with button:

```
<style name="OrangeButton" parent="@style/custom_ButtonStyle">        
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_orange_selector</item>
    <item name="android:padding">12dp</item>
</style>
```

...then you set this control as the default control in your app:
    @style/custom_ButtonStyle

Do the same for number picker.

If the goal is to only set a style for one control, once, then you could apply the style in an xml layout you'll create that will only contain the original NumberPicker, and the `style="@style/your_style`. You'd then need to create an xml layout with a LinearLayout that wrap a NumberPicker that you styled, Inflate it, and then get this view. It sounds like it's not really optimal, though.